# How do I compare the selected item in a combobox to match my settings class in the properties

Tags: c#, combobox, compare, settings

My combobox contains 'Control', 'Alt' & 'Shift'.
My predefined string in the settings class is 'Control'.

How do i compare those 2 Strings :

1. = SelectedItem in the Combobox
2. = predefined string in the settings class

Because i want to save the changed selectedItem in my settings class, so whenever i start the application again it should load the new SelectedItem in the Combobox.

Edit: Code looking actually like this, but it wont work.

```
if (cmbModifier.SelectedItem.ToString() != ClipboardPro.Properties.Settings.Default.SavedModifier.ToString())
{
      modkey = cmbModifier.SelectedItem.ToString();

      ClipboardPro.Properties.Settings.Default.SavedModifier = modkey;
      ClipboardPro.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `SelectedItem` property returns the full listitem object you used to fill your combobox.
If you are looking for the value, you can use `SelectedValue.ToString()`

```
if (cmbModifier.SelectedValue.ToString() != ClipboardPro.Properties.Settings.Default.SavedModifier.ToString())
{
      modkey = cmbModifier.SelectedValue.ToString();

      ClipboardPro.Properties.Settings.Default.SavedModifier = modkey;
      ClipboardPro.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

}
```